# Error: LINK2019: unresolved external symbol when using operator << in a namespace

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I get the following error in windows.

I have a library L1 which has the following header file and it's implementation

```
namespace TC
{
    namespace VT
    {
        enum Value
        {
            INVALID = 0,
            Light = 1

        };

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Value value);
    }
}
```

There is another library L2 which uses the operator <<. The code compilers fine but results in a unresolved external symbol error. This means that operator << is not being located at link time.

Code in library L2.

```
bool Mock::Test(
    TC::VT::Value venue )
{

    string func(__func__);

    cout << func

         << "venue = "
         << venue

         << endl;

    return false;
}
```

cout line is the one causing the problem.

MockClient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl TC::VT::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,enum TC::VT::Value)"

Comment: Well, where is the definition? What is the error? What does your [testcase](http://sscce.org) look like? 2 years, 3 months and you should know how to ask questions by now! :)

Comment: This looks like a simple case of the library L2 is not linking to the library L1

Comment: The linker is unable to find the definition of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Value value);`

Comment: @AdityaKumar Nope, it searches a different function.

Comment: Where did you define the function `std::ostream& TC::VT::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,enum TC::VT::Value)`?

Answer (score 0):

One of three things is happening here. Either you are not linking to the object file containing the definition of the operator, you have not provided a definition for the operator or the operator has not been defined properly. Since you have stated the object file is being linked you should make sure that your definition of the operator is correct. Your definition should look like the following

```
std::ostream& TC::VT::operator<<(std::ostream& os, Value value)
{
    // ... your code here
    return os;
}
```

Or it should be wrapped in the namespace

```
namespace TC
{
    namespace VT
    {
        std::ostream& TC::VT::operator<<(std::ostream& os, Value value)
        {
            // ... your code here
            return os;
        }
    }
}
```